# IE not taking my onClick, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a pretty simple function that seems to work fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but in IE it's breaking. I'm actually trying to load this as a Windows 8 Web App, but from what I've read, that uses a more forgiving version of IE10 to output.

Say I have a `<div>` (or an `<a>` with an `href`...I've tried this as well) like so:

```
<div onClick="showSection('myTemplate.html');"></div>
```

This is my function:

```
function showSection(loca) {
    $("#optionView").show();
    $("#bookMenu").hide();
    $("#optionView").load('settings/'+loca);    
    $("#settingsButton").attr("onClick","showSettingsMain();");
}
```

Why wouldn't this work specifically in IE?

Comment: I thought the onclick attribute name had to be fully lowercase.

Comment: @lib3d Nope, that's when setting it in Javascript. In HTML, it doesn't matter. Although in certain HTML specs, it's enforced (or not)

Comment: @TheJason - Which `onClick` are you talking about? When you click your div, are you sure the `showSection()` is or isn't executing? Or are you referring to your `.attr("onClick"` part?

Comment: Add a space before your closing div tag as well.  IE has been known to ignore elements with no content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option, especially since you are using jQuery, is to not use inline event handlers.

Instead, use this HTML:

```
<div id="main_div"></div>
```

And use this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#main_div").on("click", function () {
        showSection("myTemplate.html");
    });
});
```

This may not solve your problem with IE10, but it's considered better practice...and should work consistently with all browsers.

A few other suggestions:

Instead of using `.attr` to set the `onclick` attribute of `#settingsButton`, you might as well use `on` again:

```
$("#settingsButton").on("click", function () {
    showSettingsMain();
});
```

Although I'm not exactly sure if that would have any effect on what the problem is.

Nonetheless, here's an explanation on the difference between `attr` and `prop` - [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Also, if you need to specify exactly what URL to use, even on a per-`<div>` basis, you could use a `data-*` attribute. Say this is your HTML:

```
<div class="trigger-div" data-target-url="myTemplate.html"></div>
<div class="trigger-div" data-target-url="myTemplate2.html"></div>
```

Then you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger-div").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var target_url = $this.attr("data-target-url");  // or $this.data("target-url")
        showSection(target_url);
    });
});
```

Clicking the first div will use "myTemplate.html", while clicking the second will use "myTemplate2.html".

This way, your data is embedded in your HTML, but your Javascript is unobtrusive.

Comment: It's clearly much better practice but it would be interesting to know why OP's code doesn't work on IE10.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, how would he handle changing the function he wants to run onClick tho?

Comment: @dystroy Absolutely, I wish I could reproduce/suggest something. But then again, hopefully this "better practice" would solve it anyways

Comment: This is good advice. Always avoid inline event handlers when using jQuery. Also good practice is to use prop rather than attr.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble Even without using jQuery, `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` should still be preferred/suggested. But good point :)

Comment: @dystroy I think you're referring to the `$("#settingsButton").attr(` part? Either way, you're right, and I'll add that.

Comment: I know it's redundant in this scenario, just educating the OP on prop and the attr deprecation in jQuery.

Comment: @dystroy Nevermind, I guess I didn't fully read Moby's last comment

Comment: This has turned into a fabulous educational answer, @Ian. Should be proud of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery wrong, here:

First, bind the event to the div, you'll need to add a class or id for that:

```
<div id="myEvent"></div>
```

Then, bind the event:

```
$('#myEvent').on('click', showSection( 'myTemplate.html') );
```

And your function:

```
function showSection(loca) {
    $("#optionView").show();
    $("#bookMenu").hide();
    $("#optionView").load('settings/'+loca);    
}
```

Try that way.